# How do I eject the media devices or phones that are group under the Portable Devices category since there is no eject options

Tags: mobile-phone, eject

I notice that media player or Android phones (using MTP mode) that is connect to Windows, they are usually group under the `Portable Devices` category. Under this category, when you right-click, there is no eject button.

So, how do I eject my devices (e.g. HTC T8788 group under the `Portable Devices` category as shown in the picture below)?

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

[image]

Comment: Aren't they displayed in the Safely Remove Hardware tray icon menu? If not I guess you can just disconnect them. Check the phones/devices as well, they may have an option to turn off MTP/Mass Storage mode after which they can be safely disconnected.

Comment: @Karan, the problem is that I can't find the `Eject` under the menu as shown in the picture 2 which I added now.

Comment: I understood your question fine even before you added the second screenshot. Ok, so there's no Eject option in the context menu for those devices. Your problem is that you want to safely disconnect those devices, right? I suggested a couple of alternative options you can look into, but you seem to have ignored my comment.

Comment: @Karan, I understood your first comment and I was just concerns about pulling the plug out without doing something like `Eject`. Ok, maybe I just get used to `Eject` before pulling the plug out. I don't want to cause any damage to the portable devices or the computer itself. I check the devices and notice that some phones doe not have the option to turn off MTP. Also devices such as camera or mp3 player does not have the disable option. I read that some phones can use `USB debugging mode` but it seems not working as well (cause when plug into PC, it is group under `Portable Devices'

Comment: I would advise reading the device's manual. If it doesn't show up in the Safely Remove Hardware tray icon menu (did you check?) and there's no setting on the device that you can turn on/off, I would assume that it is fine for you to just yank the cable.

Answer (score 9):

Portable devices (like phones and media players) do not need, nor can they be, ejected before removing. That's why you won’t see a "Safely Remove" option in the tray menu. You might find [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/69869/when-should-you-properly-eject-your-thumb-drive/) article useful.

The relevant information from the article is that Windows gives Portable Devices special treatment. They do not have to be ejected / unmounted. If it makes you feel better, though, look at your notifications (if not Android 4.4.2 YMMV). You'll see "USB connected" as "Media sync (MTP)." Tap it and choose "Charge phone." Windows no longer sees your phone as a Portable Device.